# laptop cannot boot without external drive after installing GRUB there

Tags: 10.10, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on an external drive, Grub too. Now I cannot boot my laptop without that external device. Could there be a way to choose between Windows 7 bootloader and grub at the same time? I want to be able to boot my laptop without the external driver.

Could it be done without reinstalling Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) is your solution. You can enjoy your Windows Bootloader while keeping GRUB.

Comment: Dude i read the description and feel it's totally the solution. Are you using it ? I'll try to switch to windows, install and see the magic myself. Appreciated.

Comment: I used it before, now I'm loving BURG. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Grub overwrite your windows bootloader because Grub is not installed on your external drive but on your laptop drive.

Two things to do :

- Restore your Windows bootloader
- Install the Grub bootloader on your external drive so that Grub only appear when you choose to boot on that drive

**How to restore your Windows bootloader**

- Start Windows with a rescue or boot disk then run `fdisk /mbr`
- OR Start Ubuntu, install lilo and restore your MBR(Master Boot Record)

  `sudo apt-get install lilo`

  `sudo lilo -M  /dev/sda mbr` (assuming that your boot partition is on /dev/sda)

**How to install Ubuntu on your external drive without corrupting your windows bootloader**

- Start Ubuntu installation process with LiveCD
- Select "Specify partitions manually"

  [image]
- Choose partition on your external drive for your datas
- Choose the partition to install your Boot loader : here choose the partition on your external drive **Caution :** default value is `/dev/sda` that is your netbook internal drive, you have to change default value !

  [image]
- Go on with your installation the classic way

Using this method, your system will boot on windows unless you plug your external drive and choose it as boot disk (using <kbd>F12</kbd> or other special key at startup).

I use this system with Windows on my laptop and Ubuntu on a usb key and it works fine.

Comment: I'll do this every time I got to reinstall Ubuntu. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

What you should've done is keep the Windows bootloader in place, and install grub on the external drive. If you are very new to this, I think there will be people making easier suggestions. Otherwise, try the instructions here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/ and also maybe here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really should learn more about this.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you appear new here, I'll assume you don't know this yet. If you find a particular question or answer _useful_ , you can click the ^ button to "upvote" it, and vice versa. And if a certain answer actually "answers" your question, then you can click the check mark to "accept" it as _the answer_ . But my apologies if you already knew that.

Comment: Yeah but up vote require 15 reputations. My apology for not being able to return the kindness.

Comment: No apologies needed whatsoever. Glad to be of help.